# How to peek RabbitMq

Tags: rabbitmq

Is there anyway to look at the next message in RabbitMq without actually dequeuing the message. From what I understand that only thing you can do is dequeue the message without acknowledging and letting the message TTL expire and then it will be made active again (keeping its original priority) in the queue.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no.

You can dequeue the message and `nack` it with the option `requeue=true`

as:

`channel.basicNack(envelope.getDeliveryTag(), false, true);`

or you can use the `basicGet` function